# Using Apache Ant to deploy through firewalls

Tags: ant, grant-login-access

I'm wondering if anyone has much experience with using the Apache Ant command line for deploying code into their sandbox. We had this working great but recently our wonderful network administrators began to insert a private certificate in the firewall and now the certification fails validate correctly on the server side when trying to push code from my local system into my sandbox.

I've added the text of our internal key into the KEYS file but that doesn't seem to resolve the problem.

Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated.